# Make hit counter per user profile on PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, profile, hitcounter

I have a problem with this code for make a hit counter per user profile on PDO (MYSQL), on page loads not update and not show the counter, only text "Visits:", the value remains at "0".

```
$id = $profile_data['username'];

$statement = $db->query("SELECT `visits` FROM `users` WHERE id='$id'");
$record = $statement->fetchAll();

if(sizeof($record) != 0)
{
 $counter = $record[0]['counter']++;
 $db->exec("UPDATE `users` SET visits='$counter' WHERE id='$id'");
 echo "Visits: " .$counter;
}
else
{
 $db->exec("INSERT INTO `users` (id, visits) VALUES ('$id', 1)");
 echo "Visits: 1";
}
```

Comment: There's no point in using PDO if you aren't utilizing bound parameters. As for your current issue, enable `error_reporting` to discover that `'counter'` is not the in SELECTs result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pulling the fields `visits` from the database, you need to change:

```
$counter = $record[0]['counter']++;
```

to:

```
$counter = $record[0]['visits']++;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, was a simple error, but is how increment the visits, $counter = $record[0]['visits']+1; , I give by resolved.